# How to execute self value on loop php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code from wordpress and will execute their self value in for loop php, code like this:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x++) {
    $reply_to_level_1 = get_post_meta( bbp_get_reply_id(), '_bbp_reply_to', true );
}
```

I want last output get from last loop., like this:

```
$reply_to_level_1 = get_post_meta( bbp_get_reply_id(), '_bbp_reply_to', true ); // first
$reply_to_level_2 = get_post_meta( $reply_to_level_1, '_bbp_reply_to', true ); // second
$reply_to_level_3 = get_post_meta( $reply_to_level_2, '_bbp_reply_to', true ); // third (output)
```

Explain:

- Value from `$reply_to_level_1` used for second loop item
  (`$reply_to_level_2`)
- Value from `$reply_to_level_2` used for third loop
  item as final output (`$reply_to_level_3`)

How to make it,

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to keep the previous values, you could do something like:

```
$reply = bbp_get_reply_id();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x++) {
    $reply = get_post_meta($reply, '_bbp_reply_to', true );
}
var_dump($reply);
```

So you set the initial value and then use the result of the function to set the next values.

Comment: Thanks for answer,